# Telling git to ignore files that end with ~ in ubuntu

Tags: git, text

I am not sure if this is ubuntu specific as I just switched from windows. Please let me know if I should ask this elsewhere.

I am using version control for some local repositories. Some of the files have a ~ at the end and I don't need these files. For example, I have test.m and test.m~ simultaneously. Other text files have the same issue too.

I want to include ALL files that end with ~ in .gitignore but I am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

a line with `*~` in your .gitignore file should do it. Here is an example from the default .gitignore file for my yelp-tools git clone:

```
$ cat /home/doug/temp-yelp-git/yelp-tools/.gitignore
*~
INSTALL
Makefile
Makefile.in

/aclocal.m4
/autom4te.cache
/ChangeLog
/config.guess
/config.log
/config.status
/config.sub
/configure
/install-sh
/intltool-extract.in
/intltool-merge.in
/intltool-update.in
/missing

/tools/yelp-build
/tools/yelp-check
/tools/yelp-new
/xslt/mal-ncx.xsl
/xslt/mal-opf.xsl
```